# My google script is sending duplicate emails to recipients. I need it to only send one email

Tags: java, html, google-apps-script, html-email

I am writing code in Google Scripts to send emails to four different addresses when a Google Form is submitted. The result is that the emails are sent out to each address but in duplicate. My last trial send 12 emails to each address.

I have set up the Trigger in Google Scripts to execute when the Google Form is submitted.

I have tried placing the emails in a spread sheep and looping through the list.

I have created an array with the email addresses and created a loop with this data.

All attempts have resulted with the same duplication problem.

```
enter code here

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ContactInformation");
var ssStaff = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("StaffInformation");

var lastRowResponse = ss.getLastRow();Logger.log("lastRowResponse = " + lastRowResponse);



Logger.log("Get the current Date and Time"); // Title Logger.log Satament
var CurrentTimeStamp = ss.getRange("A"+lastRowResponse).getValue(); Logger.log("CurrentTimeStamp = " + CurrentTimeStamp);// Define CurrentTimeStamp as the Time Submitted
var GetDayNumber = CurrentTimeStamp.getDay();Logger.log("GetDayNumber = " + GetDayNumber);// Get the day number 

var weekday = new Array(7);
                  weekday[0] = "Sunday";
                  weekday[1] = "Monday";
                  weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
                  weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
                  weekday[4] = "Thursday";
                  weekday[5] = "Friday";
                  weekday[6] = "Saturday";


var DayName = weekday[GetDayNumber];Logger.log("DayName = " + DayName);// Get the day Name


var monthNames = [
    "January", "February", "March",
    "April", "May", "June", "July",
    "August", "September", "October",
    "November", "December"
  ];

  var day = CurrentTimeStamp.getDate();
  var monthIndex = CurrentTimeStamp.getMonth();
  var year = CurrentTimeStamp.getFullYear();

var FullDate = DayName + ", " + monthNames[monthIndex] + " " + day + ", " + year;Logger.log("FullDate = " + FullDate);// Get the FullDate




ss.getRange("F"+lastRowResponse).setValue("no"); Logger.log("Email1Sent = " + ss.getRange("F"+lastRowResponse).getValue());
ss.getRange("G"+lastRowResponse).setValue("no"); Logger.log("Email2Sent = " + ss.getRange("G"+lastRowResponse).getValue());
ss.getRange("H"+lastRowResponse).setValue("no"); Logger.log("Email3Sent = " + ss.getRange("H"+lastRowResponse).getValue());
ss.getRange("I"+lastRowResponse).setValue("no"); Logger.log("Email4Sent = " + ss.getRange("I"+lastRowResponse).getValue());


var Name = ss.getRange("B"+lastRowResponse).getValue(); Logger.log("Name = " + Name);// Name given on Contact Form
var Email = ss.getRange("C"+lastRowResponse).getValue(); Logger.log("Email = " + Email);// Email given on Contact Form
var Subject = ss.getRange("D"+lastRowResponse).getValue(); Logger.log("Subject = " + Subject);// Subject given on Contact Form
var EmailBody = ss.getRange("E"+lastRowResponse).getValue(); Logger.log("EmailBody = " + EmailBody);// EmailBody given on Contact Form

var OrganizerSignature = ssStaff.getRange("A2").getValue() + " and " + ssStaff.getRange("A3").getValue() + ", TEDxBlaine Organizers";

var OrganizerEmail1 = ssStaff.getRange("B2").getValue();
var OrganizerEmail2 = ssStaff.getRange("B3").getValue();

var ReasonSummaryHTML = "<html><head><style>img {width: 100%;}</style></head>"+
"<body lang=EN-US style='tab-interval:.5in'>"+
"<div class=WordSection1>"+
"<p class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align:center'><img src='https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/rzeA4cr5onMbWoPYdKOEKXBYWXTB40Dw5lzws5I7hEZD5t0mu0DpdPTNLgNVVTUbohrMd9IHq46kl03WSai9QGO-WATFS83qEwhNdzOVrplCmGIrxUO_5kr1hHHOUZ_LjB-xSk9F5pevJk7FJSqkAgHfScuZmKZGGkXU_knjkUZZl-SgAmCQZMTxDRZTbX4MQgXU6aUyE4EZAWn-9xQHnINQ86jSIR4cYP8-BKTEwXJWoVQc-S3IM9KlhLhf6aOOUUEdRBkgX_52GphmfPxKNQexywFXFx2ZHiRIf2kdVWBRzcCzWJ3ORbVbpaLPF-xkr5JbrkpEkifkZmleZy8-sMRAqL7LJKwLlPWcfbLyGGwY183PBooo94u_ptJmkb4fqzQvg5p0d4yFzGaDOGcGnyz6UXSsfjQKgg2MmHfMvsGjDVDzgXpxv4VwM2iES0ttW94jY4xO4w4TM-3Asmsx626vertCqpYAvWaY-D_BsK11FvScFBwxpbmueFotxTIihTj7s1DCV2-ySQJQ0hMw5WXQr01K-VVSZ8SdchH4zQO7H5Q2BLDZwDeisZqUZc7ZN_zFyXNIDuJlxS4p8eWeOy_wrhobjjopYSfJLGVlKiliF6GfgUGpFKnSOjuuQh4nVYRyeR7TUE_ZMD5dhg2taGEjyHQl1yE=w1920-h691-no' style='width:50%;'><o:p></o:p></span></p>"+
"<p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:12.0pt;line-height:107%;font-family:"+
"Helvetica'>Thank you for your interest in <span class=SpellE><span"+
"style='color:red'>TEDx</span>Blaine. We have received the following"+
" email from you.<o:p></o:p></span></p>"+
"<p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:12.0pt;line-height:107%;font-family:"+
"Helvetica'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>"+
"<p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:12.0pt;line-height:107%;font-family:"+
"Helvetica'>Date: "+ FullDate +"<o:p></o:p></span></p>"+
"<p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:12.0pt;line-height:107%;font-family:"+
"Helvetica'>Name:<span style='mso-spacerun:yes'>  </span>"+ Name +"<o:p></o:p></span></p>"+
"<p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:12.0pt;line-height:107%;font-family:"+
"Helvetica'>Email: "+ Email +"<o:p></o:p></span></p>"+
"<p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:12.0pt;line-height:107%;font-family:"+
"Helvetica'>Subject: "+ Subject +"<o:p></o:p></span></p>"+
"<p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:12.0pt;line-height:107%;font-family:"+
"Helvetica'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>"+
"<p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:12.0pt;line-height:107%;font-family:"+
"Helvetica'>"+ EmailBody +"<o:p></o:p></span></p>"+
"<p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>"+
"<p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>"+
"<p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:12.0pt;line-height:107%;font-family:"+
"Helvetica'>Thank you,<o:p></o:p></span></p>"+
"<p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:12.0pt;line-height:107%;font-family:"+
"Helvetica'>"+ OrganizerSignature +"<o:p></o:p></span></p>"+
"<p class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align:left'><img src='https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/J0LXjs3rBzFsSUTahPNexSC6URFJfxKnLynliJ24n24VkM0eMI52YhwiHaPB78XlCAcBpc0ptTrB5IG2VEEtzdjDOfnAGvM8NDJbP8uPS40klLf8JtzOwpvqJHaNzKsVmSXOZ6o8outl5sI8SPJ8or2ciA7CHwTugThxfwgUXS_9zv6rwfyKudEGqZbnXpJ-sXp3yHenG2ivkFNBv54QDFyHOJeUoS-0yRhZXe4e7mNWTq1-fKb9UYI0zbw5dk6sUX61UlMGReHYaSbUnvsccStpzHYnZ9xlQ44Pkbtvf7B2ghf8Y0XfMbaOnWlNixxeI7Dz9ugZMbvKcPhCQnsAFHv4QBcnACWoQ4zCskbSD7SamheLd0_fa2zRzRKW8sMno8NjJN5dfDNL6PKqS3tEgl4BmFBOay-rrAn8NCovepAozBeiqLZm3oXT_3c7Bi_cN6x8nRTW82DU4y3La0NAO6UltgGniNA-mIW1GlHhTVDnIXTosvwAOAjK6sekUtzW91Nkc23sGRb113uqLRjvZFLoU3jkksxvaJggpBHeH5PyZIDnJsIQyzpGHJ-bHVEwa7mmtst_3o13vfv1zHYn2uWdru88hDMlywE_azNyRWRf24a2vI66uRgN4fDeFruOKxyCjZPW9mZd_wnxRvGxFOyC_DhOZ8w=w314-h86-no' style='width:10%;'><o:p></o:p></span></p>"+
"</div></body></html>";



var ReasonSummaryHTML2 = "<html><head><style>img {width: 100%;}</style></head>"+
"<body lang=EN-US style='tab-interval:.5in'>"+
"<div class=WordSection1>"+
"<p class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align:center'><img src='https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/rzeA4cr5onMbWoPYdKOEKXBYWXTB40Dw5lzws5I7hEZD5t0mu0DpdPTNLgNVVTUbohrMd9IHq46kl03WSai9QGO-WATFS83qEwhNdzOVrplCmGIrxUO_5kr1hHHOUZ_LjB-xSk9F5pevJk7FJSqkAgHfScuZmKZGGkXU_knjkUZZl-SgAmCQZMTxDRZTbX4MQgXU6aUyE4EZAWn-9xQHnINQ86jSIR4cYP8-BKTEwXJWoVQc-S3IM9KlhLhf6aOOUUEdRBkgX_52GphmfPxKNQexywFXFx2ZHiRIf2kdVWBRzcCzWJ3ORbVbpaLPF-xkr5JbrkpEkifkZmleZy8-sMRAqL7LJKwLlPWcfbLyGGwY183PBooo94u_ptJmkb4fqzQvg5p0d4yFzGaDOGcGnyz6UXSsfjQKgg2MmHfMvsGjDVDzgXpxv4VwM2iES0ttW94jY4xO4w4TM-3Asmsx626vertCqpYAvWaY-D_BsK11FvScFBwxpbmueFotxTIihTj7s1DCV2-ySQJQ0hMw5WXQr01K-VVSZ8SdchH4zQO7H5Q2BLDZwDeisZqUZc7ZN_zFyXNIDuJlxS4p8eWeOy_wrhobjjopYSfJLGVlKiliF6GfgUGpFKnSOjuuQh4nVYRyeR7TUE_ZMD5dhg2taGEjyHQl1yE=w1920-h691-no' style='width:50%;'><o:p></o:p></span></p>"+
"<p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:12.0pt;line-height:107%;font-family:"+
"Helvetica'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>"+
"<p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:12.0pt;line-height:107%;font-family:"+
"Helvetica'>Date: "+ FullDate +"<o:p></o:p></span></p>"+
"<p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:12.0pt;line-height:107%;font-family:"+
"Helvetica'>Name:<span style='mso-spacerun:yes'>  </span>"+ Name +"<o:p></o:p></span></p>"+
"<p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:12.0pt;line-height:107%;font-family:"+
"Helvetica'>Email: "+ Email +"<o:p></o:p></span></p>"+
"<p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:12.0pt;line-height:107%;font-family:"+
"Helvetica'>Subject: "+ Subject +"<o:p></o:p></span></p>"+
"<p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:12.0pt;line-height:107%;font-family:"+
"Helvetica'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>"+
"<p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:12.0pt;line-height:107%;font-family:"+
"Helvetica'>"+ EmailBody +"<o:p></o:p></span></p>"+
"<p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>"+
"<p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>"+
"<p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:12.0pt;line-height:107%;font-family:"+
"Helvetica'>Thank you,<o:p></o:p></span></p>"+
"<p class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align:left'><img src='https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/J0LXjs3rBzFsSUTahPNexSC6URFJfxKnLynliJ24n24VkM0eMI52YhwiHaPB78XlCAcBpc0ptTrB5IG2VEEtzdjDOfnAGvM8NDJbP8uPS40klLf8JtzOwpvqJHaNzKsVmSXOZ6o8outl5sI8SPJ8or2ciA7CHwTugThxfwgUXS_9zv6rwfyKudEGqZbnXpJ-sXp3yHenG2ivkFNBv54QDFyHOJeUoS-0yRhZXe4e7mNWTq1-fKb9UYI0zbw5dk6sUX61UlMGReHYaSbUnvsccStpzHYnZ9xlQ44Pkbtvf7B2ghf8Y0XfMbaOnWlNixxeI7Dz9ugZMbvKcPhCQnsAFHv4QBcnACWoQ4zCskbSD7SamheLd0_fa2zRzRKW8sMno8NjJN5dfDNL6PKqS3tEgl4BmFBOay-rrAn8NCovepAozBeiqLZm3oXT_3c7Bi_cN6x8nRTW82DU4y3La0NAO6UltgGniNA-mIW1GlHhTVDnIXTosvwAOAjK6sekUtzW91Nkc23sGRb113uqLRjvZFLoU3jkksxvaJggpBHeH5PyZIDnJsIQyzpGHJ-bHVEwa7mmtst_3o13vfv1zHYn2uWdru88hDMlywE_azNyRWRf24a2vI66uRgN4fDeFruOKxyCjZPW9mZd_wnxRvGxFOyC_DhOZ8w=w314-h86-no' style='width:10%;'><o:p></o:p></span></p>"+
"</div></body></html>";





MailApp.sendEmail(Email, Subject, "--", {'noReply':true, 'htmlBody': ReasonSummaryHTML});
MailApp.sendEmail("TEDxBlaine@Gmail.Com", Subject, "--", {'noReply':true, 'htmlBody': ReasonSummaryHTML2});
MailApp.sendEmail(OrganizerEmail1, Subject, "--", {'noReply':true, 'htmlBody': ReasonSummaryHTML2});
MailApp.sendEmail(OrganizerEmail2, Subject, "--", {'noReply':true, 'htmlBody': ReasonSummaryHTML2});
```

I expect each email address to receive exactly one email per submission on the Google Form.

Comment: How did you set up the trigger? Programmatically or manually using the script editor? I ask to make sure you did not set up multiple triggers?

Comment: I set up the trigger to execute on the form Submit. There is only on trigger for this Form.

Comment: From a quick glance I can see nothing that would cause duplicate mails to be sent in the script. (Namely no for loops.) I have had numerous issues when using the "On Form Submit" trigger in the past. My advice is to set up a flag system, which processes rows and checks flag value. (If flag === "Mail Sent" do not process row, move on to next one.)

Comment: That is perfect. I ended up filling the cell after each new set data with a value of "sent" and checked for that value before executing the Email.app command. THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Pleasure Christian. (Consider answering your own question to help anyone who is looking at your post in the future.)